# Fix special chars from strings in python

Tags: python, string, encoding

The problem is that i have a column in a table of a database where some strings where uploaded incorrectly and now when I try to fix them I'm getting this error:

```py
string_to_fix = 'KIT CADENA DISTRIBUCIÃ?N' # The string has to be in capital letters
string_to_fix.encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
```

[image: Returns]

The chars Ã? are the problem and I can't fix it in any way, I tried other encodings and still nothing. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: It makes no sense to decode with a different encoding than you encoded. That's like translating text from English to German and then trying to use an Italian-to-English dictionary to translate it back.

Comment: It worked for some of them (I still need to fix the rest of the cases)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think using unicode will resolve you problem.

```
string_to_fix = 'KIT CADENA DISTRIBUCIÃ?N'.replace("Ã?", "ó")
print(string_to_fix.upper())
```

Comment: I have a lot of different cases like that one so I wanted to solve them all at once